# How to identify encoding of ESC/POS for USB label printer without driver for Mettler Toledo scale

Tags: c#, printing, usb, thermal-printer, escpos

I have a Mettler Toledo UC EVO line scale of which I would like to control the printer with my own program. The scale is a Windows PC based scale with touchscreen, load cell and printer in one.

No dirvers and libraries are provided from Mettler toledo. I have to go find out for myself.

By means of a Mettler test tool that is already installed on the scale and a USB sniffer I was able to intercept the following code:

```
01 1b 5a 02 1b 4a 03 1b 56 30 04 1b 6c 30 05 1b
4d 30 06 1b 4a 07 1b 5a 08 1b 5a 09 1b 57 34 33
32 30 34 38 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
enz..
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18
61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06
78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f
9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66
7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f
98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1
9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66
66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81
80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19
e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18
61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18
7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18
61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06
78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f
9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66
7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f
98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1
9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66
66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81
80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19
e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18
61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18
7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18
61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06
78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f
9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66
7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f
98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1
9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66
66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81
80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19
e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18
61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18
7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18
61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06
78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f
9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66
7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f
98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1
9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66
66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81
80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19
e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18
61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18
7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18
61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06
78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f
9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66
7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f
98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1
9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66
66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81
80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19
e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18
61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18
7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18
61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06
78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f
9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66
7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f
98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1
9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66
66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81
80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19
e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18
61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18
7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18
61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06
78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f
9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66
7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f
98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1
9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66
66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81
80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19
e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18
61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18
7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18
61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06
78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f
9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66
7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f
98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1
9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81 80 66 7e 18 7e 66
66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 18 61 81
80 66 7e 18 7e 66 66 7f 9e 18 61 e1 9e 06 78 19
e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
66 1f 98 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 60 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 06 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 19 e0 66 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 66 1f 98 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 19 e0 66 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
04 00 66 1f 98 00 01 e7 e7 1f 90 00 00 06 60 00
00 fc f0 81 83 00 00 19 e0 66 00 c0 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 66 1f 98 00 02 14 00 80
98 00 00 06 60 00 00 81 08 c2 44 80 00 19 e0 66
01 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 66 1f
98 00 02 12 00 40 94 00 00 06 60 00 00 41 08 a4
28 40 00 19 e0 66 02 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 05 00 66 1f 98 00 01 22 00 4f 94 00 00 06
60 00 00 21 00 84 28 40 00 19 e0 66 02 10 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 80 66 1f 98 00 00 c1
07 50 92 00 00 06 60 00 00 70 80 84 28 40 00 19
e0 66 02 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 80
66 1f 98 00 01 21 08 d0 12 00 00 06 60 00 00 80
80 84 28 40 00 19 e0 66 02 10 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 04 40 66 1f 98 00 02 10 88 50 11 00
00 06 60 00 00 80 40 84 28 40 00 19 e0 66 02 10
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f c0 00 00 00 00
02 10 88 50 bf 00 00 00 00 00 00 84 20 84 28 40
00 00 00 00 02 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
04 00 00 00 00 00 02 10 48 50 90 00 00 00 00 00
00 84 10 82 44 80 00 00 00 00 01 20 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 01 e0 47 8f
10 00 00 00 00 00 00 79 fb e1 83 00 00 00 00 00
00 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
enz..
```

[Full HEX file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QD--3Yd9ds5lELT_MWLE6M4CyZwzu9eUS1we6kHIoA8/edit?usp=sharing)

It seems that there are ESC/POS commands in between. And there seems to be a count for every new ESC command.

I have made a C# app where I can control the printer by means of LibUSB. If I use the feedEvoBtn_Click method here, it will be printed by the printer. So there is communication with the printer and my program

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private UsbDevice _evoLinePrinter;
        private UsbEndpointWriter _evoEndpointWriter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _evoLinePrinter = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(new UsbDeviceFinder(0x0EB8, 0x300C));
        }

        private void openEvoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                _evoLinePrinter.Open();

                IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = _evoLinePrinter as IUsbDevice;
                if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
                {
                    wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1);

                    wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(0);
                }

                _evoEndpointWriter = _evoLinePrinter.OpenEndpointWriter(WriteEndpointID.Ep02, EndpointType.Bulk);
                
                eventBox.Items.Add("Open reader/writer evo line");   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventBox.Items.Add(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void feedEvoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x1b, 0x53 }, 1000, out int outer);
                eventBox.Items.Add("Feed evo line printer");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventBox.Items.Add(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        private void testLabelEvoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int lenght;              
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x01, 0x1b, 0x5a }, 1000, out lenght);
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x02, 0x1b, 0x4a }, 1000, out lenght);
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x03, 0x1b, 0x56, 0x30 }, 1000, out lenght);
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x04, 0x1b, 0x6c, 0x30 }, 1000, out lenght);
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x05, 0x1b, 0x4d, 0x30 }, 1000, out lenght);
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x06, 0x1b, 0x4a }, 1000, out lenght);
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x07, 0x1b, 0x5a }, 1000, out lenght);
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x08, 0x1b, 0x57, 0x34, 0x33, 0x32, 0x30, 0x34, 0x38, 0x30 }, 1000, out lenght);
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(new byte[] { 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, }, 1000, out lenght);
                _evoEndpointWriter.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Line one\n\rline two\n\r"), 1000, out lenght);

                eventBox.Items.Add("Print test label evo line printer");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventBox.Items.Add(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Nothing happens without putting the count before the feed command.

The printer is probably controlled by ESC/P commands. Only I can't manage to just print a standard text.

When I use the testLabelEvoBtn_Click method, something happens to the printer, and after a few clicks a label comes out. There is just no text to be seen. This method does the same as the test tool, only with its own text in it. This produces the following result in the usb sniffer

[The result of using testLabelEvoBtn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAEu2.png)

When I look at the HEX code sent from Mettler's test tool, I also don't see that this is sent to the printer as ASCII, while my own program does.

Can anyone explain to me what this encoding is that the test tool sends to the printer? I hope that this way I can control the printer myself with text, a barcode and possibly a logo.

Thanks

Comment: The user guide only tells you to do something manually, so why not check if your vendor has a support program like developer registration/contract for API information? [UC Evo User's Guide](https://www.mt.com/dam/RET_DOCS/UC_Evo_User_Guide.pdf), [UC Evo CT User's Guide](https://www.mt.com/dam/RET_DOCS/64092826_R01_UC_EvoCT_UG_EN.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, Mettler Toledo does not want to answer questions or offer support for small businesses. They only want to offer this information to big sellers...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your hex trace, the commands don't seem to match any usual ESC/POS standard:

```
01 1B 5A                    [ESC Z]
02 1B 4A                    [ESC J]
03 1B 56 30                 [ESC V 0]
04 1B 6C 30                 [ESC l 0]
05 1B 4D 30                 [ESC M 0]
06 1B 4A                    [ESC J]
07 1B 5A                    [ESC Z]
08 1B 5A                    [ESC Z]
09 1B 57 34333230343830 ..  [ESC W "4320480" ...]
```

However, the last one seems to be your actual print data - as a *bitmap image*, not as text.

The initial 7 ASCII numbers problably indicate 432 dots/pixel width and (0)480 lines height.

And then every bit of the following bytes are one dot/pixel - although it seems the line direction is mirrored/reversed.

I'm not a C# programmer, but this tiny bit of Ruby produces an image from your hex (part after the ASCII width/heigh info in `bitmap`):

```ruby
width_bytes = width/8
(0..height).each do |line|
  line_bytes = bitmap[line*width_bytes, width_bytes].unpack('C*')
  line_bytes.reverse.each do |byte|
    print byte.to_s(2).gsub("0"," ").rjust(8).reverse
  end
  print "\n"
end
```

Some parts of the output (scroll right):

```
                                                                                               1111111                                                                                                 1111                  111                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                               1111111                                                                                                 1111                  111                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                             1111111                11                                                                                                 1111                  111                                  111111                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                           11111111111              11                                                                                                                                                          1111111111                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                          1111     1111             11                                                                                                                                                         1111    1111                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                          111       111             11                                                                                                                                                        111       111                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                         111         111            11               111111              11111   11          1111111           111   111111        11111111            111111111                              111        111         1111111             1111111          11   111111            11111   11          111111                                                                     
                                                                         111         111            11             1111111111          11111111 111         111111111          111  1111111        11111111            111111111                             111         11         111111111           111111111         111 11111111         11111111 111        1111111111                                                                   
                                                                         111                        11            1111    1111        1111    11111        111     111         111 11111111             111                  111                             111                   111     111         111     111        11111    1111       1111    11111       1111    1111                                                                  
                                                                          111                       11            111      111        111      1111       111       111        111 111                  111                  111                             111                  111       111       111       111       1111      111       111      1111       111      111                                                                  
                                                                          111111                    11            111      111        111       111       111       111        11111                    111                  111                             111                  111       111       111       111       111       111       111       111       111      111                                                                  
                                                                           11111111                 11                      11       111        111      111         111        111                     111                  111                             111                 111         111     111         111      111       111      111        111                 11                                                                  
                                                                              11111111              11                      11       111        111      111         111        111                     111                  111                             111     1111111     111         111     111         111      111       111      111        111                 11                                                                  
                                                                                 111111             11               111111111       111        111      111111111111111        111                     111                  111                             111     1111111     111         111     111111111111111      111       111      111        111          111111111                                                                  
                                                                                    1111            11             11111111111       111        111      111111111111111        11                      111                  111                             111         111     111         111     111111111111111      111       111      111        111        11111111111                                                                  
                                                                                     111            11            1111      11       111        111      111                    11                      111                  111                             111         111     111         111     111                  111       111      111        111       1111      11                                                                  
                                                                                     111            11           111        11       111        111      111                    11                      111                  111                             111         111     111         111     111                  111       111      111        111      111        11                                                                  
                                                                         11          111            11           111       111       111        111      111                    11                      111                  111                             1111        111     111         111     111                  111       111      111        111      111       111                                                                  
                                                                        1111         111            11           111       111        111       111       111        11         11                      111                  111                              111        111      111       111       111        11       111       111       111       111      111       111                                                                  
                                                                         111         111            11           111      11111       111      1111       111       111         11                      111                  111                              1111       111      111       111       111       111       111       111       111      1111      111      11111                                                                 
                                                                          1111     1111             11           1111    11 111       1111    11111        1111    1111         11                      111                  111                               1111     1111       111     111         1111    1111       111       111       1111    11111      1111    11 111                                                                 
                                                                           11111111111       111111111111111      11111111  11111      11111111 111         1111111111          11               111111111111111             111                                11111111111         111111111           1111111111        111       111        11111111 111       11111111  11111                                                               
                                                                             1111111         111111111111111       111111    1111       111111  111           111111            11               111111111111111             111                                  111111             1111111              111111          111       111         111111  111        111111    1111                                                               
                                                                                                                                                111                                                                          111                                                                                                                        111                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                111                                                                          111                                                                                                                        111                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                      111       111                                                                          111                                                                                                              111       111                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                       111      111                                                                         111                                                                                                                111      111                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                       1111    111                                                                         1111                                                                                                                1111    111                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                        111111111                                                                    111111111                                                                                                                  111111111                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                          111111                                                                     1111111                                                                                                                      111111
```

```
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11      1111  11      1111  11    1111    11    11    1111  11111111  11  11  11  11  111111    11    111111  11  11        11      11    11    11      11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11      1111  11      1111  11    1111    11    11    1111  11111111  11  11  11  11  111111    11    111111  11  11        11      11    11    11      11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11      1111  11      1111  11    1111    11    11    1111  11111111  11  11  11  11  111111    11    111111  11  11        11      11    11    11      11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11      1111  11      1111  11    1111    11    11    1111  11111111  11  11  11  11  111111    11    111111  11  11        11      11    11    11      11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11      1111  11      1111  11    1111    11    11    1111  11111111  11  11  11  11  111111    11    111111  11  11        11      11    11    11      11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11      1111  11      1111  11    1111    11    11    1111  11111111  11  11  11  11  111111    11    111111  11  11        11      11    11    11      11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11      1111  11      1111  11    1111    11    11    1111  11111111  11  11  11  11  111111    11    111111  11  11        11      11    11    11      11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11      1111  11      1111  11    1111    11    11    1111  11111111  11  11  11  11  111111    11    111111  11  11        11      11    11    11      11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11                                                                        11  11                                                                        11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11                                                                        11  11                                                                        11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                         11  11      1111  11                                                                        11  11                                                                        11  111111    11  11                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                              11         11  11      1111  11                   11     11      1    1111  111111                     11  11                         1  111111   111  111111  1111                  11  111111    11  11           1                                                                                                             
                                                                                                             1  1        11  11      1111  11                  1  1   1  1    11   1    1      1                     11  11                        11  1       1          1 1    1                 11  111111    11  11          11                                                                                                             
                                                                                                            1    1       11  11      1111  11                 1    1 1    1  1 1   1    1     1                      11  11                       1 1  1      1          1  1    1                 11  111111    11  11         1 1                                                                                                             
                                                                                                            1    1       11  11      1111  11                 1    1 1    1    1        1    1                       11  11                       1 1  11111  1          1   1  1                  11  111111    11  11         1 1                                                                                                             
                                                                                                            1    1       11  11      1111  11                 1    1 1    1    1       1    111                      11  11                      1  1  1    1 1 111     1     11                   11  111111    11  11        1  1                                                                                                             
                                                                                                            1    1       11  11      1111  11                 1    1 1    1    1       1       1                     11  11                      1  1       1 11   1    1    1  1                  11  111111    11  11        1  1                                                                                                             
                                                                                                            1    1       11  11      1111  11                 1    1 1    1    1      1        1                     11  11                     1   1       1 1    1   1    1    1                 11  111111    11  11       1   1                                                                                                             
                                                                                                            1    1                                            1    1 1    1    1     1    1    1                                                111111 1    1 1    1   1    1    1                                            111111                                                                                                            
                                                                                                             1  1                                              1  1   1  1     1    1     1    1                                                    1  1    1 1    1  1     1    1                                                1                                                                                                             
                                                                                                              11                                                11     11    11111 111111  1111                                                     1   1111   1111   1      1111                                                 1
```